# How to retrieve if an item in a CheckedListBox is checked or not? Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, checkboxlist

I have a `foreach()` statement running through all items inside a `CheckedListBox`.

**How can I know if a item is or not checked?**

If useful here's the code:

```
foreach (object user in checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.Items)
{
    // Privileged = if the user is checked he has privileges;
    alias = user.ToString().Substring(user.ToString().Length - 3);
    SelectUserID = new SqlCommand(Properties.Resources.SelectUserID + alias, TeamPWSecureBD);
    userIDAuth = (int)SelectUserID.ExecuteScalar();

    InsertAuths.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idPass", idPass);
    InsertAuths.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUser", userIDAuth);
    InsertAuths.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Privileged", idPass);

    //Code not finished
}
```

Comment: `isChecked()` or something like that ? ( `user.isChecked()`  ? )

Comment: @Furtiro I wish it was that simple

Comment: `CheckedListBox` has a property `CheckedItems` which is a collection of the checked items.

Comment: [`CheckState `](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkstate(v=vs.110).aspx) is a little more complex than `bool`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Arvin had given the right answer but idkw he edited to a more confuse way of solving the problem.

**The code below is working like a charm** so please to the person who edited the correct answer stop messing around.

```
foreach (object user in checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.Items)
{
      Privileged = checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.CheckedItems.Contains(user);
      ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.Items.Count; i++)
  {
    CheckState checkState = checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.GetItemCheckState(i);
    //CheckState.Checked
    //CheckState.Indeterminate
    //CheckState.Unchecked
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code :

```
foreach (object user in checkedListBox.Items)
{
    bool Privileged = checkedListBox.GetItemCheckState(checkedListBox.Items.IndexOf(user)) == CheckState.Checked;
}
```

Comment: This is actually wrong. The [CheckedItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) collection includes both the Checked and the Indeterminate items.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
foreach (CheckBox user in   checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{

}
```

Comment: The CheckedItems collection includes both the Checked and the Indeterminate items.

Answer (score 0):

`CheckedListBox` has a property `CheckedItems` which is a collection of the checked or indeterminate items.

```
var items = checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.CheckedItems;
```

*UPDATE*
I tested adding items to a `CheckedListBox` and they did not appear under the `CheckedItems` property suggesting that by default they are initialized with the value `Unchecked`.

Comment: Wrong. The CheckedItems collection includes both the Checked and the Indeterminate items.

Comment: Not according to msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx.

Comment: Read closer: `Remarks: The collection is a subset of the objects in the Items collection, representing only those items whose System.Windows.Forms.CheckState is Checked or Indeterminate. The indexes in this collection are in ascending order.`

Comment: That's a fair point but after testing creating a `CheckedListBox` and adding items to it, none of them appeared in the `CheckedItems` Property. This suggests that the default value on adding is `Unchecked` rather than `Indeterminate`. So the answer is still correct.

Comment: Well, if the states never change we wouldn't need to test them anyway. And no, the answer would be correct if it said _which is a collection of the checked  or indeterminate items_..

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
                ArrayList selected = new ArrayList();
                for (int i = 0; i < chkRoles.Items.Count; i++) //chkRoles being the CheckBoxList
                {
                    if (chkRoles.GetItemChecked(i))
                        selected.Add(chkRoles.Items[i].ToString()); //And I just added what was checked to the Arraylist. String values
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
foreach(ListItem item in checkedListBoxUsersWhoSee.Items){    
   if (item.Selected){
       // LOGIC HERE
   }
}
```